# is really all of the Handler objects for a particular thread receive the same message

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

Quoting from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

> Inside the Handler, override the handleMessage() method. The Android system invokes this method when it receives a new message for a thread it's managing; all of the Handler objects for a particular thread receive the same message.

My doubt is here  : **all of the Handler objects for a particular thread receive the same message**

I have created a activity, which have below code

```
@Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            self = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"HAndle MainActivity: "+msg.what);
                };
            };
            sen = new Sender(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()), Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
            sen.start();
            sen.repeatMsg();
        }
```

Where sender is a thread, which creates a `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

```
public class Sender extends Thread{


    protected static final String TAG = "Sender";
    private Looper mLooper;
    private Handler uiHandler;
    private int mPriority;
    public Sender(Handler handler,int priority) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mPriority = priority;
        uiHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG,"Inside run");
        Looper.prepare();
        synchronized (this) {
            mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
            notifyAll();
        }
        // setPriority(mPriority);
        Process.setThreadPriority(mPriority);
        Looper.loop();

        Handler msgHandler = new Handler(mLooper){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(TAG,"Inside handleMessage "+msg.what);
            }
        };
    }

    public Looper getLooper() {
        if (!isAlive()) {
            return null;
        }

        // If the thread has been started, wait until the looper has been
        // created.
        synchronized (this) {
            while (isAlive() && mLooper == null) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return mLooper;
    }


    public void repeatMsg() {
Log.e(TAG,"Inside repeatMsg");
        Timer t = new Timer();
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                Message m = Message.obtain();
                m.what = 1000;
                h.dispatchMessage(m);//sendMessage(m);
                repeatMsg();
            }
        };
        t.schedule(tt, 2000);


    }



}
```

What i expect is , the dispatched message should be received by the `self` handler, because both handlers bound to same thread, and is what the quoted statement states. But `self's` `handleMessage` is never called.

Why this mess?? What i mis understood??

What i should do to get my expected behaviour?

Also, Consider again a `SeconMainActivity`, which is similar to `MainActivity`, On some click event, say, the `SeconMainActivity` is launched, with same `onPostExecute` of `MainActivity`. Meanwhile, the `Sender` thread is still repeating the message. Now, who will receive the `handleMessge` call??

1. MainActivity ?
2. SecondMainActivity ?
3. Handler inside Sender Thread ?
4. None !

Update : Year 2018 , the doc still reads the same

Comment: how self Handler is to receive anything if you dont call self.sendMessage ?

Comment: @pskink, then what `all of the Handler objects for a particular thread receive the same message.` would mean ?? calling `self.sendMessage`, and wherever(say in four activities and 2 services) you have handlers bound to `mainlooper` will receive a call to `handleMessage` ??

Comment: i don't know what they meant,  i know however that a Message is received only by the Handler that sent it

Comment: @pskink but the handle message would be called in the thread to which the handler is attached to,  am I right?

Comment: Yes, this statement is completely incorrect - `Message`s are only delivered to their specified target `Handler`, and to no other. You can confirm this by looking at the source code of `MessageQueue` and `Looper`.

Comment: You'd think they would have corrected the documentation after 3 years. Very confusing. Thanks for pointing this out.